# reading video frames in parallel with opencv and Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have to read frames from a video in parallel with multiprocessing & queues using opencv in Python and I'm getting an error with my code.
This is my code, and I don't know where my problem is.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import cv2
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def read_frames(q1,q2):
        while True :
                frame = q1.get()
                if frame=='Done':
                        break
                R=frame[:,:,0]
                G=frame[:,:,1]
                B=frame[:,:,2]
                y = (np.uint8)((0.299 * R)+ (0.587 *G) +( 0.114 *B))
                q2.put(y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        q1 = mp.Queue()
        q2 = mp.Queue()
        processes =[mp.Process(target=read_frames, args= (q1,q2)) for i in rang$
        for p in processes:
                         p.start()

        # feed the processes
        # read input file and send to the processes the frames:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('gou.avi')
        lines = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        cols = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        fourcc_ver = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc_ver, fps, (cols,lines),False)
       # y = np.empty(shape=(lines,cols),dtype=np.uint8)
        while(cap.isOpened()):
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                # as long as new frames are there
                if ret==True:
                        q1.put(frame)
                        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                                         break
                else:
                     break
        q1.put('Done')



        for p in processes:
                         p.join()
        for p in processes:
                result=[q2.get()]
#       result.sort()
#       results = [r[1] for r in results]
        for i in result:
                out.write(i)
        # Release everything if job is finished
        cap.release()
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: with this 'y' i'm converting the video from rgb to black and white

Comment: If you're getting an error, post it so others can use it to help you diagnose your code.

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer in explaining what your problem is, at a minimum, you need to explain the error you're getting, and what you've tried already to resolve it. I'd strongly recommend reading [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then editing your question to improve it, if you want to get good answers.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is add all the frames to a list[] and then use list references such as frame = list[] and then address frames by location on the list: frame[0] or frame[1:4]